# How to apply a function to a sequence of nodes in XSLT

Tags: xslt, sequence, xslt-2.0

I need to write an XSLT function that transforms a sequence of nodes into a sequence of strings. What I need to do is to apply a function to all the nodes in the sequence and return a sequence as long as the original one.

This is the input document

```
<article id="4">
    <author ref="#Guy1"/>
    <author ref="#Guy2"/>
</article>
```

This is how the calling site:

```
<xsl:template match="article">
    <xsl:text>Author for </xsl:text>
    <xsl:value-of select="@id"/>

    <xsl:variable name="names" select="func:author-names(.)"/>

    <xsl:value-of select="string-join($names, ' and ')"/>
    <xsl:value-of select="count($names)"/>
</xsl:function>
```

And this is the code of the function:

```
<xsl:function name="func:authors-names">
    <xsl:param name="article"/>

    <!-- HELP: this is where I call `func:format-name` on
         each `$article/author` element -->
</xsl:function>
```

What should I use inside `func:author-names`? I tried using `xsl:for-each` but the result is a single node, not a sequence.

Comment: Please add an example for desired output.

Comment: It is confusing that in the title of the question you want "to apply a function to a sequence of nodes", however in your code you are calling the function with an argument-value that is a single node. Also confusing is the fact that you are not specifying the type for the argument and the return type of the function. This makes the question very difficult to understand. I always recommend to anyone that starts using XSLT to always specify types: for variables, for function arguments, for template parameters and global parameters, for the type of the output from a template.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`<xsl:sequence select="$article/author/func:format-name(.)"/>` is one way, the other is `<xsl:sequence select="for $a in $article/author return func:format-name($a)"/>`.

I am not sure you would need the function of course, doing

```
<xsl:value-of select="author/func:format-name(.)" separator=" and "/>
```

in the template of `article` should do.

Comment: What if the transformation is more complex than a simple call to function?

Comment: I think your question about "How to apply a function to a sequence of nodes" has been answered. If you need more help with more complex content and more complex output it is best if you ask a new question which clearly describes the sort of input you have for the function and the type of function result you want. There are some ways to construct the function result as a sequence in the function body as well as having that interact with the `as` attribute on the function but it is difficult to elaborate on that here in a comment. Ask a new question with details and I am sure we can help.

Answer (score 1):

If only a sequence of @ref values should be generated  there is no need for a function or xsl version 2.0.

```
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="1.0">
    <xsl:output method="html" />

    <xsl:template match="article">
        <xsl:apply-templates select="author" />
    </xsl:template>
    <xsl:template match="author">
        <xsl:value-of select="@ref"/>
        <xsl:if test="position() !=last()" >
            <xsl:text>,</xsl:text>
        </xsl:if>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:styleshee
```

This will generate:

```
   #Guy1,#Guy2
```

Update:
Do have the string join by `and` and have a count of items. Try this:

```
<xsl:template match="article">
    <xsl:text>Author for </xsl:text>
    <xsl:value-of select="@id"/>

    <xsl:apply-templates select="author" />

    <xsl:value-of select="count(authr[@ref])"/>
</xsl:template>
<xsl:template match="author">
    <xsl:value-of select="@ref"/>
    <xsl:if test="position() !=last()" >
        <xsl:text> and </xsl:text>
    </xsl:if>
</xsl:template>
```

With this output:

```
  Author for 4#Guy1 and #Guy20
```