# XSLT: Create nested nodes using single node transformation

Tags: xml, xslt

I want to create nested XML nodes using a single node from an XML structure, I tried but unable to bring the nested XML structure, Can some please help me, I am unable to get the expected behavior.

**XML Sructure:**

```
<job[n]/> -> 0...n
<person-non-active/> -> 1
<removed> -> 1
```

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<root>
    <person>
        <job1/>
        <job2/>
        <person-non-active>
            <removed>
                <job3/>
                <job4/>
            </removed>
        </person-non-active>
    </person>
    <person>
      <bio>
        <job1/>
        <job2/>
        <person-non-active>
            <removed>
                <job3/>
            </removed>
        </person-non-active>
      </bio>
    </person>
   <person>
        <person-non-active>
            <removed>
                <job3/>
                <job4/>
            </removed>
        </person-non-active>
    </person>
</root>
```

**XSL Used:**

```
<xsl:template match="person-non-active">
        <person>            
            <xsl:if test="(count(../*) &gt; 1)">
                <job>
                    <xsl:attribute name="status"><xsl:text>active</xsl:text></xsl:attribute>
                    <xsl:attribute name="jobs">
                        <xsl:for-each select="../*">
                            <xsl:if test="not(name() = 'person-non-active')">
                                <xsl:value-of select="name()"/><xsl:text>, </xsl:text>
                            </xsl:if>                            
                        </xsl:for-each>                
                    </xsl:attribute>
                </job>
            </xsl:if>
            <xsl:if test="(count(./removed/*) &gt; 0)">
                <job>
                    <xsl:attribute name="status"><xsl:text>non-acitve</xsl:text></xsl:attribute>
                    <xsl:attribute name="jobs">
                        <xsl:for-each select="./removed/*">
                            <xsl:value-of select="name()"/><xsl:text>, </xsl:text>
                        </xsl:for-each>                
                    </xsl:attribute>
                </job>
            </xsl:if>
        </person>
    </xsl:template>
```

**Output Received:**

```
<person>
 <job status="active" jobs="job1, job2, "/>
 <job status="non-acitve" jobs="job3, job4, "/>
</person>
```

**Expected Output**

```
<person>
    <job status="active" jobs="job1, job2, ">
        <job status="non-acitve" jobs="job3, job4, "/>
    </job>
</person>
<person>
 <bio>
    <job status="active" jobs="job1, job2, ">
        <job status="non-acitve" jobs="job3, "/>
    </job>
 </bio>
</person>
<person>
    <job status="non-acitve" jobs="job3, job4, "/>
</person>
```

"person-non-active" element should be used for match

Comment: Which XSLT version (and which parser) are you using? Your expected output is not really clear... you want for each person to have a <job> to list active jobs and to also contain a nest <job> to list non-actives jobs?

Comment: I used XSLT 3.0, yes i need each <person> to have the <job> and nest the non-active.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Couldn't you do simply:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" 
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>
<xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

<xsl:template match="person">
    <person>
        <job status="active">
            <xsl:attribute name="jobs">
                <xsl:for-each select="*[not(self::person-non-active)]">
                    <xsl:value-of select="name()"/>
                    <xsl:text>, </xsl:text>
                 </xsl:for-each>                
            </xsl:attribute>
            <job status="non-active">
                <xsl:attribute name="jobs">
                    <xsl:for-each select="person-non-active/removed/*">
                        <xsl:value-of select="name()"/>
                        <xsl:text>, </xsl:text>
                     </xsl:for-each>                
                </xsl:attribute>
            </job>
        </job>
    </person>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

---

Note that I have changed `status="non-acitve"` to `status="non-active"`.

---

### *Added in response to expanded question:*

This is considerably more complicated, esp. if you want to preserve the wrapper elements of active jobs (such as `bio` in your example), without knowing their names in advance.

If `job`s are the **only** elements with no child elements, you could do something like:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" 
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>
<xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

<!-- identity transform -->
<xsl:template match="@*|node()">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

<!-- parent of active jobs -->
<xsl:template match="*[*[not(*)]]">
    <xsl:copy>
        <job status="active">
            <xsl:attribute name="jobs">
                <xsl:for-each select="*[not(*)]">
                    <xsl:value-of select="name()"/>
                    <xsl:text>, </xsl:text>
                 </xsl:for-each>                
            </xsl:attribute>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="*[*]"/>
        </job>  
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

<!-- ancestor of non-active jobs -->
<xsl:template match="person-non-active">
    <job status="non-active">
        <xsl:attribute name="jobs">
            <xsl:for-each select=".//*[not(*)]">
                <xsl:value-of select="name()"/>
                <xsl:text>, </xsl:text>
             </xsl:for-each>                
        </xsl:attribute>
    </job>  
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, This is will do the trick, but the complex part is it should match the "person-non-active", must work and create the nested elements based on <person-non-active> element.

Comment: I suppose that' would be possible too, but I don't see why it needs to be complex when it can be simple.

Comment: The reason is there are chances the element <person-non-active> may fall under the different elements. eg. <person><bio>...<person-non-active>...</bio></person>, so I chose <person-non-active> as key to match.

Comment: So use `<xsl:for-each select=".//person-non-active/removed/*">`. You would have the same problem getting the active jobs from the context of `person-non-active`. There is no advantage in doing in from there.

Comment: I just modified the code with few eg. please have a look, help if possible :)

Comment: This is problematic. I could give you an answer based on your current example, but if there can be other elements, we need a **rule** to determine what is a "job" - such as "it is only element with no children" (which fits your example, but may not be true in others).

Comment: See the addition to my post.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a way this could be done.
I think all that is missing are the separators for the values in job/@jobs.

I have based some of the code on this answer : [How to apply a function to a sequence of nodes in XSLT](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16250886/how-to-apply-a-function-to-a-sequence-of-nodes-in-xslt)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
    exclude-result-prefixes="#all"
    version="2.0">

  <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes"/>

  <xsl:template match="person">
      <root>
        <xsl:copy>
            <job>
                <xsl:attribute name="status" select="'active'"/>
                <xsl:variable name="seqj"><xsl:sequence select="for $j in *[starts-with(local-name(.),'job')] return local-name($j)"/></xsl:variable>
                <xsl:attribute name="jobs"><xsl:value-of select="$seqj"/></xsl:attribute>
                <job>
                    <xsl:attribute name="status" select="'non-active'"/>
                    <xsl:variable name="seqj"><xsl:sequence select="for $j in person-non-active/removed/*[starts-with(local-name(.),'job')] return local-name($j)"/></xsl:variable>
                    <xsl:attribute name="jobs"><xsl:value-of select="$seqj"/></xsl:attribute>
                </job>
            </job>
        </xsl:copy>
      </root>
  </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

You can see it working here : https://xsltfiddle.liberty-development.net/pNmC4J3

Comment: Thanks for the answer, This is will do the trick, but the complex part is it should match the "person-non-active", must work and create the nested elements based on <person-non-active> element.